# Homestead project runs only when used 127.0.0.1 in the hosts file

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I am new to the Homestead and virtualbox/vagrant world. I went through some video tutorials on how to strat working with Homestead.
Everything went smoothly until the last step. It says we need to add the IP address mention in the Homestead.yaml file into the hosts file.

I did that, but it always gave me the following error:

This site can’t be reached
dev.test refused to connect.
Search Google for dev test 8000
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

My hosts file looks something like this:
192.168.10.10 dev.test

But when I use 127.0.0.1 dev.test it works perfectly fine.

I don't know what's happening.
Even the official documentation says we should 192.168.10.10 dev.test in the /etc/hosts file.

Where am I going wrong??

### Here's my Homestead.yaml file

ip: "192.168.10.10"

memory: 2048

cpus: 1

provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/laravel.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/laravel

folders:
    - map: /var/www/Laravel

```
  to: /home/vagrant/Laravel
```

sites:
    - map: dev.test

```
  to: /home/vagrant/Laravel/test/public
```

databases:
    - homestead

Comment: in Homestead.yaml 192.168.10.10 ?

Comment: screen your hosts, please

Comment: Screen or paste here your Homestead.yaml if you can

Comment: @bretanac93 I have updated my question with the Homestead.yaml file

Comment: Did you check if you are using the port 8000 in your host OS?, because vagrant maps the ports to the clients, ie: `80 -> 8000`, if you have the port 8000 in use in your client, maybe there is some error and the nginx server doesn't execute in your guest.

Comment: @bretanac93 when I used sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
,I got this response:
VBoxHeadl 6016 pritambohra   26u  IPv4  65583      0t0  TCP *:8000 (LISTEN)

What does that mean??

Comment: @bretanac93I got my mistake. I was using dev.test/8000 in the browser even after using 192.168.10.10 in the host file that's why it wasn't working and was thus getting an error. Sorry for all the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found my mistake.
I was trying to access my web app using port 8000 even after using **192.168.10.10 dev.test** in the hosts file. I should have simply used **dev.test** in the browser to access the web app.

Silly Mistake.
I makes perfect sense to use **dev.test:8000** in the browser if the hosts file reads **127.0.0.1 dev.test**